# Why does Gtk.Widget.set_size_request and Gtk.Window.set_default_size result in different Window sizes with same values?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

Why does set_size_request(800,600) called on DrawingArea widget (also tested with Gtk.Button) result in a Window of size 958 x 791 px, whereas set_default_size(800,600) called on the Window result in an appropriately sized window (as measured by taking a screenshot of just the Window and looking at it's resolution)? I would understand if there would be a little discrepancy in height, due to the window header bar, but such a difference in both width and height doesn't make sense to me. The documentation doesn't hint at anything like that. If someone could enlighten me, that'd be great!

Here's a code example written in vala:

```
using Gtk;
using Cairo;

public class SizeTest : Gtk.Window {

    public SizeTest () {
        this.title = "Size test";
        this.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);
        //set_default_size (800, 600); // Window size -> 800 x 600 px

        var drawing_area = new DrawingArea ();
        drawing_area.set_size_request (800, 600); // Window size -> 958 x 791 px
        add (drawing_area);
    }

    static int main (string[] args) {
        Gtk.init (ref args);

        var test = new SizeTest ();
        test.show_all ();

        Gtk.main ();

        return 0;
    }
}
```

@Zongren Zhang, thank you for testing it. I tried it again, splitting it in two applications, like you did. The size of both windows is quite different for me. I tried it on both my monitors - same thing.

Btw, I am using elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki, installed libgtk-3-0 version is 3.18.9.

Comment: AFAIK Gtk doesn't make any promises about a Window's initial size; if you don't set an initial size or any geometry hints, the initial size can be anything. It likely depends on your window manager.

Comment: But what confuses me most is that 800x600 px (which is actual physical pixels on the screen, right?!) seems to be something different to the Window than it is to the DrawingArea. When set as the Window's default size, a screenshot of it has exactly that resolution. When, on the other hand, I set it as the size of the DrawingArea, a square drawn a 799,599 just becomes visible in the bottom right corner, while an object at 0,0 is located in the top left corner. The Window size adjusts, of course to accomodate the DrawingArea, but the Window is now more than 150 px larger in both directions.

Comment: @Rawing I think I figured it out! You were right, setting a Window's default size is no guarantee that it really shows up with that size. Thank you for the hint! Although different default Window sizes result in different actual sizes, it's been fooling me. It's never been the right size. The screenshot tool fooled me even further ;D. Opening the screenshots in Gimp, I realized that there is transparent space around the window. It must somehow fetch that default size, take a screenshot of the window and then make the space that was allocated to the window but is not used by it transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments it seems you already checked that the size is the same but translating this to an actual answer.

Lets add a signal to inform us of the window size:

```
this.configure_event.connect ((event) =>  {
   print ("Window::Size (px) Width: %d Height: %d\n", event.width, event.height);
   return false;
});
```

The resulting code will be:

```
using Gtk;

public class SizeTest : Gtk.Window {

    public SizeTest () {
        this.title = "Size test";
        this.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);
        this.configure_event.connect ((event) =>  {
            print ("Window::Size (px) Width: %d Height: %d\n", event.width, event.height);
            return false;
        });
        set_default_size (800, 600); // Window size -> 800 x 600 px

        var drawing_area = new DrawingArea ();
        //drawing_area.set_size_request (800, 600); // Window size -> 800 x 600 px
        add (drawing_area);
    }

    static int main (string[] args) {
        Gtk.init (ref args);

        var test = new SizeTest ();
        test.show_all ();

        Gtk.main ();

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Running the test application using either of the options (`Gtk.Widget.set_default_size` vs `Gtk.Window.set_default_size`) will output:

> Window::Size (px) Width: 800 Height: 600

There's a difference though, using `Gtk.Widget.set_size_request` will not allow the widget to be smaller than the given size (and the `Gtk.Window` as a consequence) while using `Gtk.Window.set_default_size` will permit the window to "shrink" below the initial size.

From the API:

- [`Gtk.Widget.set_default_size`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Window.set_default_size.html):

  > Sets the default size of a window.
  >
  > If the window’s “natural” size (its size request) is larger than the
  >   default, the default will be ignored. More generally, if the default
  >   size does not obey the geometry hints for the window (
  >   set_geometry_hints can be used to set these explicitly), the default
  >   size will be clamped to the nearest permitted size.
  >
  > Unlike set_size_request, which sets a size request for a widget and
  >   thus would keep users from shrinking the window, this function only
  >   sets the initial size, just as if the user had resized the window
  >   themselves. Users can still shrink the window again as they normally
  >   would. Setting a default size of -1 means to use the “natural” default
  >   size (the size request of the window).
- [`Gtk.Widget.set_size_request`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Widget.set_size_request.html):

  > Sets the minimum size of a widget; that is, the widget’s size request
  >   will be at least width by height.
  >
  > You can use this function to force a widget to be larger than it
  >   normally would be.
  >
  > In most cases, set_default_size is a better choice for toplevel
  >   windows than this function; setting the default size will still allow
  >   users to shrink the window. Setting the size request will force them
  >   to leave the window at least as large as the size request. When
  >   dealing with window sizes, set_geometry_hints can be a useful function
  >   as well.
  >
  > Note the inherent danger of setting any fixed size - themes,
  >   translations into other languages, different fonts, and user action
  >   can all change the appropriate size for a given widget. So, it's
  >   basically impossible to hardcode a size that will always be correct.
  >
  > The size request of a widget is the smallest size a widget can accept
  >   while still functioning well and drawing itself correctly. However in
  >   some strange cases a widget may be allocated less than its requested
  >   size, and in many cases a widget may be allocated more space than it
  >   requested. ... The size request set here does not include any margin
  >   from the Widget properties margin-left, margin-right, margin-top, and
  >   margin-bottom, but it does include pretty much all other padding or
  >   border properties set by any subclass of Widget.